# Replace part of string with variable using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

Is there a way to replace only a part of a string with a random number using sed or awk?

From a URL list file, i need to replace each GET url param that matches the pattern with a random number.

Example:

- https://example.com?param1=somevalue&param2=somevalue
- https://otherexample.com?param1=somevalue&param2=somevalue

Replace "param1=" with random number

So, after replace:

- https://example.com?param1=512512412&param2=somevalue
- https://otherexample.com?param1=9568478547&param2=somevalue

Answer (score 0):

basically same syntax for sed and awk - the extended regex is

```
s/(param)([0-9])=([0-9]{3,})/\1\2= { … fill in rand number u want … } /g'
```

awk side, either mawk or gawk

```
match($0, /(param)([0-9])=([0-9][0-9]+)/);

$0 = substr($0,1,RSTART + 6) 
     {…fill in rand #…} 
    substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH);
```

Unfortunately, since `mawk2` has neither backreferences like `\1 \2` nor bracket expansion like `{3,}` , sadly if u wanna write portable code then match is the way to go.

if u wanna stay on `gawk`, then `gensub` works reasonably okay.